# add one with arbitrary class-values

Tags: r

I want to add one arbitrary class-value column to the existing data set.As test(data set has 94 column) does not have a classification column, I want to add one with arbitrary class-values. This will be column 95

Comment: Need more information. A working example of your data would be good. Otherwise it looks like you just need cbind(data,NewCol=rep("blahblah", nrows(data))

Comment: Actually I have two data sets  one is train and other is test data set whereas train data set has one column called target which is factor variable.In the test data set doesn't have any such column but I want to add one like train.

Comment: testdata=cbind(testdata, target="whatever you want")

Comment: I want arbitrary values in (target=" " )

Comment: testdata=cbind(testdata, target=" ")

Comment: please select the check sign on the answer bellow so this question can be considered closed

Comment: In the test data set I have 100 items but I want first 90 only.code for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
testdata=cbind(testdata, target=" ")
```